# Как в python заменить список if else с заданными параметрами на input значения

Tags: python, list, input

Вот часть кода, необходимо параметры 1.14-2.14 заменить на значения вводимые с клавиатуры, прошу помощи)

```
    F_kr = math.pi * (d1 ** 2) / 4
    F_a = math.pi * (r2 ** 2)

    nc = F_a / F_kr
    k = float(ui.comboBox_4.currentText().replace(',', '.')) 
    if k == 1.14:                        #список
        eps_c = 4.0389 * (nc ** 1.2207)
    if k == 1.15:
        eps_c = 4.0929 * (nc ** 1.2282)
    if k == 1.16:
        eps_c = 4.1478 * (nc ** 1.2357)
    if k == 1.17:
        eps_c = 4.2027 * (nc ** 1.2433)
    if k == 1.18:
        eps_c = 4.2532 * (nc ** 1.2511)
    if k == 1.19:
        eps_c = 4.3066 * (nc ** 1.2588)
    if k == 1.20:
        eps_c = 4.3591 * (nc ** 1.2666)
    if k == 1.21:
        eps_c = 4.4108 * (nc ** 1.2745)
    if k == 1.22:
        eps_c = 4.4595 * (nc ** 1.2804)
    if k == 1.23:
        eps_c = 4.5088 * (nc ** 1.2904)
    if k == 1.24:
        eps_c = 4.5599 * (nc ** 1.2984)
    else:
        sds = 1
```

Comment: опечатался необходимо параметры 1.14-1.24 заменить на значения вводимые с клавиатуры

Comment: я думаю что можно представь это как взаимоотношение параметра к выражению, то есть некоторый список `ключ : [значение1, значение2]`, где ключ будет собственно вашим параметром, включащий в себя значения, например `1.14 : [4.0389,1.2207]`

Comment: ошибки не выдает, я пытался менять на input значения, скажу честно на данном этапе я чайник, поэтому тяжеловато дается. при запуске кода открывается интерфейс где данный параметр k идет как список с готовыми значениями, а мне необходимо готовые значения поменять на вводимые

Comment: Подумайте все таки в сторону создания динамического словаря, пополняемый от значений на ввод с проверкой существования на параметр

Comment: так-то контекста вашей формы нет, поэтому я в ответе реализую пример консольный

Comment: но по хорошему должна быть форма ввода и редактирования в словарь, а уже из словаря формировать список комбобокса

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать динамический словарь, в котором мы будем через `input` наполнять значениями формата `ключ: [значение1, значение2]`, далее мы проверяем `k` на наличие в данном словаре, в успехе мы производим расчёт `eps_c`, иначе приравняем `sds` к `1`.

```
import json

# Создаем пустой словарь для хранения данных
my_dict = {}

# Запрашиваем у пользователя ключи и соответствующие значения для заполнения словаря
for i in range(3):
    key = float(input(f"Введите ключ {i}: "))
    value1 = float(input(f"Введите значение1 {i}: "))
    value2 = float(input(f"Введите значение2 {i}: "))
    my_dict[key] = [value1, value2]

# Выводим окончательно заполненный словарь
print(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4))

# Запрашиваем ключ, для которого будем выполнять операцию
k = float(input(f'Введите ключ по которому делаем операцию: '))

# Инициализируем значение nc как 1, контекст не считываю, поэтому так
nc = 1

# Проверяем, есть ли введенный ключ в словаре
if k in my_dict:
    # Вычисляем eps_c по формуле, используя значения из словаря и nc
    eps_c = my_dict[k][0] * (nc ** my_dict[k][1])
    print(f'eps_c = {eps_c}')
else:
    # Если ключа нет в словаре, выводим sds со значением 1
    sds = 1
    print(f'sds = {sds}')
```

Данный пример опускает много контекста из вашего кода, по хорошему у вас должна быть отдельная форма ввода данных значений и сохранение их как `json` словарь, с дальнейшим формированием из данного словаря вашего комбобокса. В данном примере так же опущен контекст переменной `nc`, тем не менее терминал выводит следующее:

```
Введите ключ 0: 1.14
Введите значение1 0: 4.0389
Введите значение2 0: 1.2207
Введите ключ 1: 1.15
Введите значение1 1: 4.0929
Введите значение2 1: 1.2282
Введите ключ 2: 1.16
Введите значение1 2: 4.1478
Введите значение2 2: 1.2357
{
    "1.14": [
        4.0389,
        1.2207
    ],
    "1.15": [
        4.0929,
        1.2282
    ],
    "1.16": [
        4.1478,
        1.2357
    ]
}
Введите ключ по которому делаем операцию: 1.15
eps_c = 4.0929
```